# using same array in different functions

Tags: arrays, model-view-controller, url-routing

Here's the situation: I have 2 different functions and one view. I need to send data from function 1 to the view (2 arrays), and from that view i need to send data to function 2 (1 array).

Sending data from function 1 to the view is an easy job, but i don't know how to do it with function 2 because the information i would like to send to it has a function 1's array plus other new data the users entry.

I know there's no chance to send an array through URL, but i'm out of ideas.

Which is the best option for passing the data?

i send to the view this data:

admin: (part of the function 1)

```
//last part of the code
$this->data['conditions'] = $conditions;
$this->data['notselectedconditions'] = $notselectedconditions;
$this->parser->parse('admin/tools/showReport.tpl',$this->data);
```

In the view i use the information on those arrays, and user can put some new entry.

view:

```
<dt>Tipo de Usuario<dt>
    <dd><a href="{site_url()}admin/admin/reloadConditions/1">Pre Registrado</a></dd>
```

reloadConditions is function 2, the one that needs what function 1 provides plus the selection of the user in order to keep filtering the results.

The information i need to have available on function 2 is: array 'conditions' and users new entry

Comment: What's your current code ?

Comment: Why does the view need to call another function? Views shouldn't call any functions except specific helper functions for formatting the data. The data should not be processed further (following MVC conventions).

Comment: @ComFreek well then how would you send to your admin the information users entry through the view?

Comment: I think more code is needed to understand the situation of your problem and desciption of the structure of your program

Comment: @Jimena The user inputs data into some form fields. The form gets sent and your controller receives the data. It then forwards this data to the model and performs action based on the current route.

Comment: @ComFreek of course, that's the way i'm doing it for the forms. In this case the user has to click in a link to keep filtering the results. But i need the user's previous selection too

Comment: @Jimena Either save the filtering options in the $_SESSION or pass it in the URL (recommended).

Comment: @ComFreek but i can't pass an array in the url, right?

Comment: @Jimena That's certainly possible. Let's say you want to receive `$_GET['arr'] = [1,2,3];`, then specifying this URL would be sufficient: `arr[]=1&arr[]=2&arr[]=3` (PHP does the magic for you).

Comment: @ComFreek should i change the tag <a> to <form> tag, to send the new info with POST?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41203/discussion-between-comfreek-and-jimena)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long discussion and some clarifications in chat, here is the solution I came up with:

```
<?php

function addQueryParameters($url, $params) {
    $paramsStr = http_build_query($params);

    $fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
    $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    $interUrl = '';
    if ($query === NULL) {
      $interUrl = '?';
    }
    if ($fragment !== NULL) {
        $interUrl = '&';
    }

    $interUrl .= $paramsStr;

    if ($fragment !== NULL) {
        $pos = strpos($url, '#' . $fragment);
        $url = substr($url, 0, $pos) . $interUrl . substr($url, $pos);
    }

    return $url;
}

function linkifyFilterConditions($url, $conditions) {
    return addQueryParameters($url, array('conditions' => $conditions));
}

// Tests
// TODO: replace by unit tests
var_dump(linkifyFilterConditions('http://example.com/blub', [1,2,3]));
var_dump(linkifyFilterConditions('http://example.com/blub#a', [1,2,3]));
var_dump(linkifyFilterConditions('http://example.com/blub?a=b#a', [1,2,3]));
```

Usage (in OP's views):

```
$href = 'yourscript?conditions[]=a'; 
$href = linkifyFilterConditions($href, $conditions); 

echo '<a href="' . $href . '">Test</>';
```

Answer (score -1):

How about puting you arrays in `$_SESSION`?

see here http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Comment: That is a really bad suggestion. PHP has to load the whole session data each time the session is loaded (i.e. almost always).